Flask tests : RuntimeError: Working outside of application context
I see here that I don't really understand the concept of "context"... My app is at the very beginning and I only have a Welcome page. Now I added the flask_login routine with very simple usage : no password, simply go to /login and you'll be connected. The app is working well, but I can't test it.
I'm using the app factory paradigm.
My conftest.py file is :
import pytest

from app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app('test')
    return app

Now I can write simple test which is OK :
def test_index(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get('/')
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert b"Welcome" in response.data

But this test which implies context usage fails :
def test_login(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get(url_for('auth.login'), follow_redirects=True)
        assert request.path == url_for('main.index')
        assert b"Connected" in response.data

The error is :
        except LookupError:
>           raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
E           with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py:519: RuntimeError

I've tried different possibilities like having the client created in the conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def client():
     app = create_app('test')
     with app.test_client() as client:
         yield client

Then the test is :
def test_login(client):
    response = client.get(url_for('auth.login'), follow_redirects=True)
    assert request.path == url_for('main.index')
    assert b"Connected" in response.data

The result is the same with the same error.
